# How to pass a javascript object to a PHP file while using ajax

Tags: javascript, object, serialization

I have a javascript object which I want to pass to a PHP file while using jQuery's ajax-implementation.

I've tried to directly pass it to it but this doesn't work, because it isn't escaped or anything. I've tried to use JSON.stringify but this isn't working for me either.

Is there a way to 'serialize' a javascript object to a POST-string?

Update, I'm using JSON.stringify() again. The result is:

The result of JSON.stringify() is:

```
{\"label\":\"Borne, Overijssel, Nederland\",\"value\":\"Borne, Overijssel, Nederland\",\"geocode\":{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"Borne\",\"short_name\":\"Borne\",\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Borne\",\"short_name\":\"Borne\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_2\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Overijssel\",\"short_name\":\"OV\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_1\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Nederland\",\"short_name\":\"NL\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"]}],\"formatted_address\":\"Borne, Nederland\",\"geometry\":{\"bounds\":{\"ca\":{\"b\":52.2832527,\"f\":52.3151634},\"ea\":{\"b\":6.688658900000064,\"f\":6.801415300000031}},\"location\":{\"Ya\":52.3002366,\"Za\":6.753725799999984},\"location_type\":\"APPROXIMATE\",\"viewport\":{\"ca\":{\"b\":52.2832527,\"f\":52.3151634},\"ea\":{\"b\":6.688658900000064,\"f\":6.801415300000031}}},\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"]}}
```

When I do a `json_decode` it results to NULL. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of what your doing? Your code here, and maybe a jsfiddle.net example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your passing an object as a string thats in legitmate JSON format, to PHP try using

`json_decode()` on the php side of things. Example

```
<?php
   $ojb = json_decode($_POST['my_json_string']);
?>
```

What this will do is turn your object into an array or object depending on which version of PHP you are using, and in some cases the object will turn into an array with multiple objects in it.. example:

```
Array(
    [0] stdClass (
            'key1'=>'val1'
            'key2'=>'val2'
            'key3'=>'val3'
         )
)
```

which I know the above isnt a good representation, but its a representation in the lines there of.

After that PHP side you can work with the variable `$ojb` like any other array/object.

```
$something = $ojb[0]->key1;
```

**EDIT**
I notice your string now. The fact that the quotes are escaped in the string, breaks the fact that its a JSON object, with that you can do one of two things.. Either just pass the object to PHP through your post/get as is, without running it through strigify or.. you could try on the PHP side, if there is a need to strigfy it..

`$ojb = stripslashes($_POST['my_json_string']); $ojb = json_decode($ojb);`

which will attempt to remove the slashes from the quotes, before putting it through the decode process.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Actually I think I read your question wrong.. this may not be the solution you seek.

Comment: Hi Crhiss, well, I'm on a road. What I'm doing is working now. But I'm unable to correctly json_decode the post-value.

Comment: The returnvalue of the json_decode-call is NULL. I believe my string isn't correct then.

Comment: Thats plausible, I'd have to read up on it again, can't remember what json decode returns if invalid. But null is possible

Comment: I've added the output in the question.

Comment: Hi Chris, it was relaxtime with the girl for me ;) I've tried to use the stripslashes. This worked, though I could have figured this out myself as well ;) Thanks for your help! +1 and accepted. Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a **raw body** of the POST request. The raw data would be the result of a `JSON.stringify` call which would mean that you should specify an appropriate `Content-Type` header.

```
$.ajax(url, {
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  processData: false // prevent escaping and other processing
});
```

You can then deserialize the object in PHP like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

The raw request body is mapped onto the special path `php://input`